# Jacoco doesn't find Kotlin files coverage in Kotlin and Java maven project from kotlin's tests

Tags: java, kotlin, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have project with Kotlin and Java source folders and Kotlin and Java test source folders.  But when I try to check coverage, Jacoco can't find coverage for Kotlin classes.

@Godin I tryed to apply **build-helper-maven-plugin** from your answer [answer on similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55765833/code-coverage-kotlin-and-java-together-using-maven-jacoco) for adding more source/test directories, but result is the same "rule violated for KotlinExample class lines covered is ratio 0.0..."

**UPDATE** Coverage only works if I cover Kotlin classes from Java tests. But from Kotlin’s tests this doesn’t work.

Higly appreciate any help.

My pom is

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<properties>
    <main.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</main.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    <kotlin.version>1.3.72</kotlin.version>
    <kotlin.compiler.incremental>true</kotlin.compiler.incremental>
    <jacoco.version>0.8.3</jacoco.version>
    <sonar.inclusions>src/main/**</sonar.inclusions>
    <sonar.exclusion.001>**/dto/**</sonar.exclusion.001>
    <sonar.exclusion.002>**/stub/**</sonar.exclusion.002>
    <sonar.skip>true</sonar.skip>
</properties>

<dependencies>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>*</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>env.properties</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <jvmTarget>${jdk.version}</jvmTarget>
                <compilerPlugins>
                    <plugin>spring</plugin>
                </compilerPlugins>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                   <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs>
                            <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDir>
                        </sourceDirs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs>
                            <sourceDir>${basedir}/src/test/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            <sourceDir>${basedir}/src/test/java</sourceDir>
                        </sourceDirs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-compile</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-testCompile</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>java-compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>java-testCompile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>${sonar.exclusion.001}</exclude>
                    <exclude>${sonar.exclusion.002}</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <destFile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-unit-test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <dataFile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/jacoco-ut-report</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>check</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <dataFile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
                        <rules>
                            <rule>
                                <element>CLASS</element>
                                <limits>
                                    <limit>
                                        <counter>LINE</counter>
                                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                        <minimum>0.8</minimum>
                                    </limit>
                                    <limit>
                                        <counter>BRANCH</counter>
                                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                        <minimum>0.8</minimum>
                                    </limit>
                                </limits>
                            </rule>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: just add into the jacoco plugin  <includes> <include>src/main/kotlin</include></includes> inside the configuration tag

Answer (score -1):

If you are using 0.8.3 or similar versions of jacoco-maven-plugin, please make sure data file is defined, and use the following configuration for the plugin.

```
<execution>
  <id>jacoco-check</id>
  <goals>
    <goal>check</goal>
  </goals>
  <configuration>
    <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
    <rules>
      <rule>
        <element>BUNDLE</element>
        <limits>
          <limit>
            <counter>INSTRUCTION</counter>
            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
            <minimum>0.17</minimum>
          </limit>
        </limits>
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </configuration>
</execution>
```

This code ensures overall coverage of 17%.

Please verify this using

**mvn clean verify**

command.
And add this for the config manifest

```
<configuration>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>META-INF/**</exclude>
      </excludes>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer but Kotlin files still isn't covered

Comment: did you try my code in your jacoco config file ? Can you send log error file pls

Comment: Yep, I tried your decision but I insert my own minimum coverage value 80%.
I have only 1 class in each folder: .kt and .java. That's why the final lines of console is:
-
[INFO] Analyzed bundle 'com.mycompany’ with 2 classes
[WARNING] Rule violated for com.mycompany: instructions covered ratio is 0.4, but expected minimum is 0.8
Rule violated for bundle com.mycompany: instructions covered ratio is 0.4, but expected minimum is 0.8

Answer (score -1):

try that :

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<properties>
    <main.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</main.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    <kotlin.version>1.3.72</kotlin.version>
    <kotlin.compiler.incremental>true</kotlin.compiler.incremental>
    <jacoco.version>0.8.3</jacoco.version>
    <sonar.inclusions>src/main/**</sonar.inclusions>
    <sonar.exclusion.001>**/dto/**</sonar.exclusion.001>
    <sonar.exclusion.002>**/stub/**</sonar.exclusion.002>
    <sonar.skip>true</sonar.skip>
</properties>

<dependencies>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>*</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>env.properties</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <jvmTarget>${jdk.version}</jvmTarget>
                <compilerPlugins>
                    <plugin>spring</plugin>
                </compilerPlugins>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                   <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs>
                            <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDir>
                        </sourceDirs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs>
                            <sourceDir>${basedir}/src/test/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            <sourceDir>${basedir}/src/test/java</sourceDir>
                        </sourceDirs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-compile</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-testCompile</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>java-compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>java-testCompile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>${sonar.exclusion.001}</exclude>
                    <exclude>${sonar.exclusion.002}</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <destFile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-unit-test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <dataFile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/jacoco-ut-report</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>check</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <dataFile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
                        <rules>
                            <rule>
                                <element>CLASS</element>
                                <limits>
                                    <limit>
                                        <counter>LINE</counter>
                                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                        <minimum>0.4</minimum>
                                    </limit>
                                    <limit>
                                        <counter>BRANCH</counter>
                                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                        <minimum>0.4</minimum>
                                    </limit>
                                </limits>
                            </rule>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see the difference between this and my example. I wonder if you just decreased the percentage, don't you?

Comment: Of course decrease will be work. But the question is: Why Jacoco can't find coverage for Kotlin classes?